# Get all rows that exist for last month while converting to UTC

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone, utc

So I'm trying to get all rows that pertain to dates during last month (i.e. between first and last of the month). I'm also trying to convert to UTC while doing this.

Here are two ways that I have:

```
WHERE ARRIVE_DT_TM BETWEEN CCLSQL_CNVTDATETIMEUTC(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1),'MM'),1,126,1) AND CCLSQL_CNVTDATETIMEUTC(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')-(1/86400),1,126,1)
```

Another way I have is below, but I don't know where to put the convert commmand.

```
WHERE ARRIVE_DT_TM BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1) AND LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1)+1)
```

Any thoughts? is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: The Oracle `DATE` data type has no time zone information, thus in principle it is not possible to convert a `DATE` value into UTC time. What is the data type of `ARRIVE_DT_TM`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data type of column `ARRIVE_DT_TM` is `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` I would suggest this one:

```
WHERE ARRIVE_DT_TM BETWEEN
   FROM_TZ(CAST(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1), 'MM') AS TIMESTAMP), TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr') ) AND
   FROM_TZ(CAST(LAST_DAY(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1))) AS TIMESTAMP), TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr'))
```

Some conversions are needed, because `ADD_MONTHS` and `LAST_DAY` return a `DATE` value. However, a `DATE` values has no time zone information and `FROM_TZ` requires a `TIMESTAMP` value.

`SYSDATE` and `SYSTIMESTAMP` are given in the time zone of database server's operating system, so you can combine then.

Explicit conversion to UTC is not required. Internally all comparisons of `TIMESTAMP WITH {LOCAL} TIME ZONE` are performed on UTC anyway.

In case column `ARRIVE_DT_TM` is a `DATE` value, you can convert it to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, i.e.

```
WHERE FROM_TZ(CAST(ARRIVE_DT_TM AS TIMESTAMP), <time zone>) BETWEEN ...
```

Put in the valid `<time zone>`, this has to be known by the application. Again, explicit conversion to UTC is not required.